# How to automate a process in hex editor

Tags: windows-10, automation, hex-editor

Im trying to make a mod work for ps4 which according to a video basically requires extracting a file, going in the folder, opening the xml file in hex editor, going in hex editor and replacing win64 to ps4 over and over again. But there like 100s of file and its getting kinda tedious. Is there a way to automate the process to something as simple as drag and drop?